# How to set up db in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, git, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor.  I downloaded a git repo of a friends project.  I want to "initiate" the database, as the local folder is in the .gitignore.

In Rails, it would be something like `rake db:setup` which would grab all of the migrations and set up the database.  How do I do something similar in Meteor? I also see that there are no `db, lib, or local` folders in the project.

My goal here is to seed the database, for which I am using `node-mongo-seeds`

Thank you!

Comment: In Meteor, seeding is part of Meteor.startup(). The actual code should be preferably written in imports/startup/server/fixtures.js. I usually indicate seeding should be done for the database by adding a setting called seed=true in settings.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor does not have an official or structured DB seeding or migrations API as Rails does.

Some apps include code that runs on startup and seed empty collections. Some community packages that perform migrations are no longer maintained.

Note that MongoDB is schemaless, so adding fields to the schema (defined in code, usually via [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)) is less "traumatic" than in SQL databases, with its pros and cons.

You can try to figure out if the application used one of the migration packages by looking at the package list (by running `meteor list` or looking at the `.meteor/packages` file).

There's also a video from a [MeteorTLV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WABQiAwqVJg) meetup regarding migrations.